# Automorphism of $G$-set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

> Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ the normalizer of
>   $H$. Then there exist a homomorphism of the opposite quotient group
>   $(N/H)^{op}$ into the symmetric group of the quotient set $G/H$:
>   $$\phi:(N/H)^{op}\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{G/H}.$$ Moreover $\phi$
>   induces an isomorphism of $(N/H)^{op}$ onto the group of automorphisms
>   of the $G$-set $G/H$.

Suppose $G$ is a group. Then $G$ operates on itself by left translation: $G$ is a left homogeneous principal $G$-set; denote it by $G_s$ .

How does the quoted result imply that the group of automorphisms of the homogeneous principal $G$-set $G_s$ is isomorphic to $G^{op}$?

Comment: Every group is isomorphic to its opposite group via inversion. Hence, you could get rid of the superscripted _op_'s.

Comment: The result you want is the special case of the quoted theorem when $H = \{e\}$.